# New to web dev JavaScript code isn't working with my html website

Tags: javascript, html

The javascript doesn't work. I just couldn't figure out what the problem is.

```js
var username = 'Molly';
var message = 'See our upcoming range';
var elName = document.getElementByld('name');
elName.textContent = username;
var elNote = document.getElementByld('note');
elNote.textContent = message;
```

```html
<html>

<hl>Elderflower</hl>
<div id="content">
  <div id="title">Howdy
    <span id="name">friend</span> !</div>
  <div id="note">Take a l ook around . . . </div>

</div>

<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: typo in `document .getElementByld('note');` remove the extra space between document and dot `.`

Comment: You can mostly figure out what's wrong by viewing the JavaScript Console of your Browser's DevTools

Comment: it still doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `getElementById()` not `getElementByld()`.

**NOTE 1:** The difference in `I` and `l` in `Id` :

```
var elName = document.getElementById('name');
__________________________________^
```

**NOTE 2:** You must learn how to use *JavaScript Console of your Browser's DevTools* since it will show clearly :

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByld is not a function

```js
var username = 'Molly';
var message = 'See our upcoming range';

var elName = document.getElementById('name');
elName.textContent = username;
var elNote = document.getElementById('note');
elNote.textContent = message;
```

```html
<hl>Elderflower</hl>
<div id="content">
  <div id="title">Howdy
    <span id="name">friend</span> !</div>
  <div id="note">Take a l ook around . . . </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Typing was mistake, Check this code as it is running as requested.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <hl>Elderflower</hl>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="title">Howdy
            <span id="var1">friend</span> !</div>
        <div id="var2">Take a look around . . . </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var username = 'Molly';
        var message = 'See our upcoming range';
        var elName = document.getElementById('var1');
        elName.textContent = username;
        var elNote = document.getElementById('var2');
        elNote.textContent = message;
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```